# Reinterpret cast void without type identifier

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting, type-erasure

I'm using type erasure (void cast) to store multiple basic types (float, bool, int etc.) in a one-to-one map. One way to reinterpret the original data type is to use a pair/union/class instead to store the value with a type identifier (e.g. pair). Is there a clean way to resolve the basic type without an identifier using C++11 without Boost?

```
std::map<int, void *> m_mymap;
// avoid std::map<int, pair<void, MyEnum> > m_mymap;

template <class T> void setValue<T>(int i_key, T i_val)
{
    m_mymap[i_key] = reinterprete_cast<void *>(i_val);
}

template <class T> T getValue<T>(int i_key)
{
    return reinterprete_cast<T>(i_val);
}

doSomeWork()
{
    for (const auto & elem : m_mymap)
    {
        auto val = some_magical_cast< ??? >(elem.second) // resolve type without a nasty switch against MyEnum 
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Edit: Update question to use void *

Comment: `void` doesn't contain any type of data you want - it contains nothing.

Comment: essentially void * cast similar to the idea of using map<int, boost::any>

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `boost::any`? It seems like it's exactly the tool for the job.

Comment: Its more a restriction against using Boost - I have used boost::any before to solve this problem. Of course std::any in C++17 isn't an option either

Comment: yes sorry it's pretty late where I am haha

Comment: There's no magical_cast, and a heterogeneous container is a bad idea in any case.

Comment: You could use a variant instead?

Comment: Do you know a variant example that would apply in this case? The material I've seen online requires the type to be known on get e.g. https://www.ojdip.net/2013/10/implementing-a-variant-type-in-cpp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> auto val = some_magical_cast< ??? >(elem.second) // resolve type without a nasty switch against MyEnum
> ```

C++ is a *statically* typed language. Every type must be known at compile time. What you're trying to do would require that the type be determined at *runtime*, based on what was put into the map.

That's not possible with anything in C++. `val` must have a single, specific type, not a type determined by executing runtime code. And every iteration of the loop must give it the same type. A union or `variant` would allow you to store one of several types, determined at runtime. But the set of types they store is fixed at compile time.

Even if `auto val` could somehow result in a series of different types, a `void*` does not contain any information which could be used to recover the type it pointed to. Notice that `boost/std::any` also lacks any ability to recover this type; you have to ask for a specific type (the difference being that if you ask for the wrong type, `any` will fail, while `void*` will give you UB).

So no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly explained by @NicolBolas, you can't.

As a viable approach/workaround, you can use a technique based on the idea of the *double dispatching*, as in the following example:

```
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

class C {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void accept(int k, T v) { std::cout << k << " " << v << std::endl; }
};

using P = void(*)(C &, int, void *);

std::map<int, std::pair<P, void*>> m;

template<typename T>
void proto(C &c, int k, void *v) {
    c.accept(k, *static_cast<T*>(v));
}

template <class T>
void set(int k, T *v) {
    m[k] = { &proto<T>, v };
}

void get(C &c, int k) {
    auto p = m[k];
    p.first(c, k, p.second);
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    double d = 1.2;

    set(0, &i);
    set(1, &d);

    C c;
    for(auto &&k: m) {
        get(c, k.first);
    }
}
```

It requires an additional class (`C` in the example).
You can add to that class different methods for different types (as an example, instead of a template method, you can use two methods that accept either an `int` or a `double`).
This way, you can have a generalized behavior as well as many type-specific ones.

Of course, it's more complicated and not for free, but otherwise you can't obtain what you are looking for.

Comment: Would the work now go into c.accept? The get here does not return a valid type so there would be many gets - 1 for get<T>, 2 for void get(int) { c.doWork } which in my opinion is less readable

Comment: @lukemtesta The work goes in `c.accept`, of course. You don't need more `get`s, you need more `accept`s.  Unfortunately, the solution doesn't aim to be readable, the aim is to be able to do something similar to what you want to achieve. Anyway, double dispatching is a widely used technique, I wouldn't define it _not readable_.